# How to Update Google Maps Marker Image when tap on the marker

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I want to change the marker icon and show info window when tapped on the marker.
My question here is **how to change** the marker icon?

**I have stored the google maps instance and tried updating it my setting iconView property of that marker**

```
func setUpMarker() {
        let markerView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "pinImage"))
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)
        marker.iconView = markerView

        storeMarker = marker
    }
```

**Method to update marker**

```
func updateMarker() {
        let markerView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "circleImage"))
        storeMarker.iconView = markerView
    }
```

But, this adds **a new icon on the previous icon**.

Answer (score 3):

In the comments you asked how to deselect the currently selected marker. That's a bit more involved. I do it something like this:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
    // `markers` is an array of all the markers currently on the map.
    markers.forEach {
        ($0.iconView as! UIImageView).image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "unselected-pin")
    }
    (marker.iconView as! UIImageView).image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "selected-pin")
    return true
}
```

---

#### Previous Answer

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapMarker marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
    print("tapped on marker")
    if storeMarker == marker {
        (marker.iconView as! UIImageView).image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "circleImage")
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Wow, that was simple. Do you know how to deselect "selected" markers when tapping another marker?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement Google map delegate method

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {}

 func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didChange position: GMSCameraPosition) {}

 func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {}
```

Comment: I have already added those delegate method can you let me know what should I do within these method.